# adding a github same name child repository to a parent repository

Tags: git, github

The child repository is the same name as a parent one.

```
git add --all
```

Does not work, I get this hint

```
warning: adding embedded git repository: repostiroy
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> repository
```

If

```
git add --all
```

does not work Then what does since I obsessively cant follow those instructions

Answer (score 0):

I feel dumb, however, the file was apparently a git repository since I had the mistake of uploading it before. If you want to know what I did, go into that file and do

```
rm -rf .git
```

Then go to the main repository and you will be good to go.